# Linebreaks not rendering in HTML

Tags: javascript

I am creating H5 dynamically and rendering a String. I am unable to create new lines. This is what I have tried so far:

```
var h5 = document.createElement('h5');
h5.appendChild(document.createTextNode("City: Chicago\nState: Illinois"));
document.body.appendChild(h5);
```

I have also tried `<br>` but it just renders as is. How do I create new lines?

Comment: Linebreaks that aren't HTML only render in `pre` elements and those with the special style `white-space: pre;`

Comment: The <br> tag only works if it's added as HTML, not text, as in your current situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

Linebreaks that aren't HTML only render in `pre` elements and those with the special `pre` style

### Solution

Use the `white-space: pre;` style

#### Using a separate CSS rule

```js
var h5 = document.createElement('h5');
h5.appendChild(document.createTextNode("City: Chicago\nState: Illinois"));
document.body.appendChild(h5);
```

```css
h5 {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

#### Javascript only solution

```js
var h5 = document.createElement('h5');
h5.style.whiteSpace = 'pre';
h5.appendChild(document.createTextNode("City: Chicago\nState: Illinois"));
document.body.appendChild(h5);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @FarazDurrani glad I could help a fellow chicagoan!

Answer (score 2):

A textnode element doesn't interpret html, that is why your html is written as text.
On the other hand the \n will be inserted in a textnode but it won't work in html H5 tag.A solution is to create a "pre" tag instead of h5, or use the innerHTMl property...

```js
var h5 = document.createElement('h5');
h5.innerHTML="City: Chicago<br>State: Illinois";
document.body.appendChild(h5);
```